# MATLAB's num2str is inconsistent

Tags: matlab

I want to receive the string representation of a number, 2 points after the dot.

I'm using MATLAB R2015a, and noticed that num2str function returns inconsistent results:

for 0.511 I get the required result (0.51):

```
num2str(0.511,2)

ans =

0.51
```

for 1.711 I get 1.7 instead of 1.71:

```
num2str(1.511,2)

ans =

1.5
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `'precision'` scalar input to `num2str` is the number of [significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). if you want to have 2 figures after the decimal point use the `'formatSpec'` string argument:

```
num2str(0.511,'%.2f')
    0.51
num2str(1.511,'%.2f')
    1.51
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [`num2str()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html):

> s = num2str(A,precision) returns a character array that represents the numbers with the maximum number of significant digits specified by precision.

In other words, the second parameter controls the total number of significant figures, not the number of decimal places.

If you want to round to two decimal places, then use the `round()` function.  You can try rounding the number before calling `num2str()`:

```
num2str(round(1.511,2))
```